# Convert JSON string to JsonResult in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, deserialization

We are trying to make mock service to serve JSON. We have plain JSON strings stored in static files and want to serve them to client as they are, without any additional wrappers.
E.g. we have json string `{"result_code":200,{"name":"John", "lastName": "Doe"}}` and we want to get json response on client just like this without any Content or Data wrappers.

We have solution where we use data contracts and deserialize json to C# objects, but that's a bit complicated and we don't need it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please be more specific **what "mock service" is** - just some API implementation (like `IMyServiceReturningJson` in test's process), real server i.e. written with ASP.Net MVC (as Jededuah +1 suggests) or some other technology/language like node.js? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by referencing System.Web.Mvc. Example in a quick console app I threw together:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Added "person" to the JSON so it would deserialize
            var testData = "{\"result_code\":200, \"person\":{\"name\":\"John\", \"lastName\": \"Doe\"}}";

            var result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(testData)
            };

            Console.WriteLine(result.Data);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

You can just return the JsonResult from the mock method.

Comment: Bad advice, this requires de-serializing and re-serializing the object to return.

Answer (score 21):

You can return a static JSON string by sending the content manually.

```
public ActionResult Tester()
{
    return Content("{\"result_code\":200,{\"name\":\"John\", \"lastName\": \"Doe\"}}", "application/json");
}
```

Sorry if that's not exactly what you're asking about

Comment: This serves the result as actual JSON, versus a body with string containing JSON. This is definitely easier to work with on the client side than the accepted answer.