# how can convert string into json result

Tags: asp.net-core, jsonresult

I am using function to get the data as a tree format. the data return from GetDepotWithDepartment as a string datatype. how can I convert the string into JsonResult

```
public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()
    {
         string lson = _unitOfWork.Department.GetDepotWithDepartment();
        return lson // error is coming cannot convert string into mvc.jsonREsult
    }
```

The data coming from the repository linq as given

```html
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "1-Depot1",
    "subs": [
      {
        "id": "1.1",
        "title": "1.Advt"
      },
      {
        "id": "1.2",
        "title": "1.Admin"
      }
    
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "2-Depot2",
    "subs": [
      {
        "id": "2.1",
        "title": "2.Sales"
      },
      {
        "id": "2.2",
        "title": "2.Admin"
      }
      
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/22692856/9695286

Comment: Karan, I tried the same way but not working

Comment: it already is json.... why are you trying to convert it to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below codes to return the json result:

```
public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()
    {
         string lson = _unitOfWork.Department.GetDepotWithDepartment();
        return new JsonResult(lson) // error is coming cannot convert string into mvc.jsonREsult
    }
```

Result:

[image]